# Lookup Pandas Dataframe comparing different size data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two pandas df that look like this

```
df1
   Amount   Price
0    5       50
1    10      53 
2    15      55
3    30      50
4    45      61

df2 
     Used amount
 0      4.5
 1      1.2
 2      6.2
 3      4.1 
 4      25.6
 5      31
 6      19
 7      15
```

I am trying to insert a new column on df2 that will give provide the price from the df1, df1 and df2 have different size, df1 is smaller

I am expecting something like this

```
df3 
     Used amount price
 0      4.5       50
 1      1.2       50
 2      6.2       53
 3      4.1       50
 4      25.6      50
 5      31        61
 6      19        50
 7      15        55
```

I am thinking to solve this, with something like this function

```
def price_function(key, table):
    used_amount_df2 = (row[0] for row in df1)
    price = filter(lambda x: x < key, used_amount_df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my own solution

1st approach:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
df2=df2.reset_index()
DF=pd.DataFrame(list(product(df2.Usedamount, df1.Amount)), columns=['l1', 'l2'])
DF['DIFF']=(DF.l1-DF.l2)
DF=DF.loc[DF.DIFF<=0,]
DF=DF.sort_values(['l1','DIFF'],ascending=[True,False]).drop_duplicates(['l1'],keep='first')
df1.merge(DF,left_on='Amount',right_on='l2',how='left').merge(df2,left_on='l1',right_on='Usedamount',how='right').loc[:,['index','Usedamount','Price']].set_index('index').sort_index()


Out[185]: 
       Usedamount  Price
index                   
0             4.5     50
1             1.2     50
2             6.2     53
3             4.1     50
4            25.6     50
5            31.0     61
6            19.0     50
7            15.0     55
```

---

2nd using `pd.merge_asof` ***I recommend this***

```
df2=df2.rename({'Used amount':Amount}).sort_values('Amount')
df2=df2.reset_index()
  pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='Amount',allow_exact_matches=True,direction='forward')\
   .set_index('index').sort_index()

Out[206]: 
       Amount  Price
index               
0         4.5     50
1         1.2     50
2         6.2     53
3         4.1     50
4        25.6     50
5        31.0     61
6        19.0     50
7        15.0     55
```

Comment: @rriveral glad it help ~

Comment: many thanks! I tried with my data set and its working, however, the data set as in de example df2 used amount is data for a month and df1 data is data for 1 week, so I am having 4 x df1 per x 1 df2

Comment: I have checked the pd.merge_asof , but I think it doesnt have such and option, would you suggest to cut the data set an iterate per week, or do you think theres an iteration for a df with a merge_asof

Comment: @rriveral sorry I did not get it , basically you are doing the amount merge, right ? so you need merge it month by month and `pd.concat`

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, basically what I am trying to do, and what the merge_asof is doing, is matching amount used = 4.5, to a value that is with in the range of 0 to 5, then assign a price, so the amount used, is a huge list of one month, but the assign price when it's merged it merged over the entire month, but the price is just for one week within that month, so it would make sense what you have said if a concat weeks, that would work definitely, but do you think this can be done with a conditional matching dates for example

Comment: @rriveral Without the data , I can only rough say , `pd.concat` is the option one , `pd.merge_asof` you can using `left_on=['date','amount']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) or `searchsorted` for create bins.

Notice: Index in `df1` has to be default - `0,1,2...`.

```
#create default index if necessary
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

#create bins
bins = [0] + df1['Amount'].tolist()
#get index values of df1 by values of Used amount
a = pd.cut(df2['Used amount'], bins=bins, labels=df1.index)
#assign output
df2['price'] = df1['Price'].values[a]
print (df2)
   Used amount  price
0          4.5     50
1          1.2     50
2          6.2     53
3          4.1     50
4         25.6     50
5         31.0     61
6         19.0     50
7         15.0     55
```

---

```
a = df1['Amount'].searchsorted(df2['Used amount'])
df2['price'] = df1['Price'].values[a]
print (df2)
   Used amount  price
0          4.5     50
1          1.2     50
2          6.2     53
3          4.1     50
4         25.6     50
5         31.0     61
6         19.0     50
7         15.0     55
```

Comment: These are the first things I thought of as well.

Comment: @piRSquared just want to share `pd.merge_asof` :)

Comment: @Wen yes of course. Been a while since I used that one

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.IntervalIndex` you can

```
In [468]: df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.Amount.shift().fillna(0),df1.Amount)

In [469]: df1
Out[469]:
              Amount  Price
(0.0, 5.0]         5     50
(5.0, 10.0]       10     53
(10.0, 15.0]      15     55
(15.0, 30.0]      30     50
(30.0, 45.0]      45     61

In [470]: df2['price'] = df2['Used amount'].map(df1.Price)

In [471]: df2
Out[471]:
   Used amount  price
0          4.5     50
1          1.2     50
2          6.2     53
3          4.1     50
4         25.6     50
5         31.0     61
6         19.0     50
7         15.0     55
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.reindex` with `method=bfill`

```
df1.set_index('Amount').reindex(df2['Used amount'], method='bfill')

             Price
Used amount       
4.5             50
1.2             50
6.2             53
4.1             50
25.6            50
31.0            61
19.0            50
15.0            55
```

---

To add that to a new column we can use

**`join`**

```
df2.join(
    df1.set_index('Amount').reindex(df2['Used amount'], method='bfill'),
    on='Used amount'
)

   Used amount  Price
0          4.5     50
1          1.2     50
2          6.2     53
3          4.1     50
4         25.6     50
5         31.0     61
6         19.0     50
7         15.0     55
```

Or `assign`

```
df2.assign(
    Price=df1.set_index('Amount').reindex(df2['Used amount'], method='bfill').values)

   Used amount  Price
0          4.5     50
1          1.2     50
2          6.2     53
3          4.1     50
4         25.6     50
5         31.0     61
6         19.0     50
7         15.0     55
```